# Dropdown in navbar open in the out of area. How to fix it?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, dropdown, angular-ui-bootstrap

Dropdown cuts in half, because it open in the out of area.

html code:

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" 
           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img style="width: 30px;" src="assets/img/navbar/user.png">
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="/auth/account">Moje konto</a>
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="/auth/user-orders">Zamówienia</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" style="cursor:pointer"
            (click)="authService.logoutUser()">Wyloguj</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

css:

```
.router{
    margin-right: 2cm;
    margin-left: 2cm;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please inspect the element and add the applied styling (CSS) to the question.

Comment: @melancia I edited the question, but I have almost nothing in css

Comment: I think the element you want to inspect is the one with the class `nav-item dropdown`.

Comment: It's  `dropdown-menu`. I add 
`.dropdown-menu { left: -3cm;
}` 
It's better but I want it to be auto.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Angular UI Bootstrap, but I would be surprised if there's no documentation to help you with that. It might be just one of the element's parents breaking the layout. To isolate the issue and be able to help you, we would need more of the CSS being applied to the page (and potentially the markup aswell).

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.3/ and https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dropdown

Comment: @melancia Thank you :)